# Hibernate hbm many to many mapping

Tags: database, hibernate, many-to-many, save, hbm

I am trying to create a one-to-many mapping between 2 objects (work with Java). I am able to save the objects in the database, but not their relationship. I have a class called "AuthorizationPrincipal" and it contains a set of "Privileges"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-mapping package="org.openmrs">

<class name="AuthorizationPrincipal" table="authorization_principal" lazy="false">


<id
    name="authorizationPrincipalId"
    type="int"
    column="authorization_principal_id"
    unsaved-value="0"
>
    <generator class="native" />
</id>

<discriminator column="authorization_principal_id" insert="false" />


<property name="name" type="java.lang.String" column="name" unique="true"
            length="38"/>


<many-to-one
    name="creator"
    class="org.openmrs.User"
    not-null="true"
/>

<property
    name="uuid"
    type="java.lang.String"
    column="uuid"
    length="38"
    unique="true"
/>
<property
    name="dateCreated"
    type="java.util.Date"
    column="date_created"
    not-null="true"
    length="19"
/>
<property
    name="policy"
    type="java.lang.String"
    column="policy"
    not-null="true"
    length="255"
/>

<!--  Associations -->

<set name="privileges" inverse="true" cascade=""
    table="authorization_principal_privilege" >
    <key column="authorization_principal_id" not-null="true"/>
    <many-to-many class="Privilege">
        <column name="privilege" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>

</class>
```

I came up with the "set" tag by following through a few tutorials and examples, but it still won't save in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see wrong is that you defined the relationship as a *many-to-many* from AuthorizationPrincipal entity, and as you say in your question you want a one-to-many relationship.

Then, you must define your set like this:

```
<set name="privileges" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
    <key column="authorization_principal_id" not-null="true" />
    <one-to-many class="Privileges" />
</set>
```

This configuration should be enough for you.

**EDIT**

If your configuration is many-to-many, then you must have a table for the relationship between *AuthoririzationPrincipal* and *Privileges* like *AuthoririzationPrincipal-Privileges*

And ypur mapping must be like this:

In AuthorizationPrincipal:

```
<set name="privileges" table="AuthoririzationPrincipal-Privileges">
    <key column="authorization_principal_id" />
    <many-to-many class="Privileges" column="privileges_id" />
</set>
```

And in Privileges:

```
<set name="authorizationPrincipals" inverse="true" table="AuthoririzationPrincipal-Privileges">
    <key column="privileges_id" />
    <many-to-many class="AuthoririzationPrincipal" column="authorization_principal_id" />
</set>
```

Comment: I think I may have made a mistake. I may need many-to-many instead of one-to-many. The object "AuthorizationPrincipal" contains a set of "Privilege" objects. And an instance of a "Privilege" object can be contained in multiple "AuthorizationPrincipal" objects. Ex. AP1 can contain priv1 and priv2, and then AP2 can contain priv2 and priv3.

Comment: Thankyou, I got the problem fixed. It was actually an issue with the transaction manager.